# How do I set nginx configuration settings on a per app basis in Dokku?

Tags: nginx, dokku

I need to increase the `client_max_body_size` setting for a single app I have installed on a Dokku Paas. I could edit the nginx configuration globally, but that would be brittle, and I would like this setting to live with the app config where possible.

I have seen some plugins that help rewrite the nginx.conf file (eg. https://github.com/mikexstudios/dokku-nginx-alt), but that seems like overkill when I only want to change a single setting.

I have also noticed the `nginx-configure` plugin hook (https://github.com/progrium/dokku/pull/189), but I could not find clear instructions on how to use this from an app (where would I put the hook script, for example?).

What is the cleanest, most maintainable and most portable method of setting a single nginx configuration parameter on a per app basis?

Comment: And what's the problem? This directive could be used anywhere

Comment: Sorry - I don't follow. What directive? My question is how do I set a particular nginx setting on per app basis.

Comment: nginx knows nothing about your app. Nginx works in terms on `server` and `location` blocks. Somewhere you have location block, that pass request to you app. You could add `client_max_body_size` directive to that block.

Comment: Did you see that this is specifically a question about dokku? I know how to configure this myself, but this is running in a PAAS environment where the nginx configuration is automatically generated. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I found this plugin which is using perl to modify the nginx.conf after deploying:
https://github.com/fabiooshiro/dokku-client-max-body-size/blob/master/nginx-pre-reload
You could conditionally modify the file per app (e.g. when a certain file in the app directory exists)

Answer (score 21):

This question is a bit old, but I ran into it while searching for a solution to the same question.

By default, dokku sites are installed in `/home/dokku/{site-name}`.

There is one main `nginx` file per app in this folder, `nginx.conf`. This file will be replaced every time you deploy so you don't want to change this.

However, you will see that this main `nginx.conf` file has the following line it in -

```
  include /home/dokku/{site-name}/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;
```

Which will include any .conf files in the `nginx.conf.d` folder.

So you can add a file called `upload.conf` (for example) to the `nginx.conf.d` folder, containing just `client_max_body_size 50M;`, and you'll achieve what you want to do.

After you create the directory and config file, ensure you `chown` them to the `dokku` user.

See https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/docs/configuration/nginx.md for further details.

Comment: i use react-router and i need to overwrite the "location / {}" and it seems i can't do that in nginx, any ideas?